# React / React-Select / Firebase : Refreshing React-Select on addition of new entry

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-select

I have a select:

```
<Select classNamePrefix="select" ref={myRef} menuPortalTarget={document.body} styles={style} placeholder="Select Foods" name="Foods" value={inputField.foods} options={options} onChange={event => handleInputChange2(index, event)} className="select selectNarrow" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

```
  const handleInputChange2 = (index, event) => {
    const values = [...inputFields];
    values[index] = event;
    setInputFields(values);
    console.log(event);
  };
```

Whereby {options} are built from a collection. On this same page I can add to this collection - after adding a new item and then opening the select it is not immediately visible until after I have chosen an already existing item. How do I get the React-Select to refresh the list each time I open it (rather than an onChange)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like we're missing some code to properly answer your question. How did you add a 'new item'? While you added to the collection, did you also update your `options` array?

Displayed options are controlled by the `options` prop. If you add a new option to this array, React-Select will rerender and the new option would be available.